# how to store nested loop values in a matrix in r

Tags: r, loops, matrix, nested-loops

I created a loop to calculate the following formula: values = 1+PE - (1+(i^w))^(1/w)) where PE and w change as follows:

```
#creation of my variables
w <- seq(1, 4, by = 0.1)
PE <- seq(1, 2, by = 0.1)

#creation of a matrix where I will be storing the results of the loop

results <- matrix(nrow= length(PE) , ncol= length(w))

#loop where w and PE are changing 

for(i in PE){
  for (j in w){
    results <- (1+i - (1+(i^j))^(1/j))
    print (results)
  }
}

results
```

If I run it I obtain a list where all my values are printed, but I face 2 problems:

i) I cannot store those values. When I print results outside the loop, I obtain 1 value and not all of them. So i cannot manipulate them to create a matrix and neither a data frame.

ii) I initially created a matrix for those values to be stored so when I add in the loop: results[i, j] I get several matrices with many NA values when I should be getting only one matrix. And this matrix should have 11 rows and 31 columns

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7ZL5.png)

Comment: `result <- sapply(w, function(j) (1+PE - (1+(PE^j))^(1/j)))` Use vector operations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results[i,j]` the way you defined doesn't work because `i` and `j` are not indexes, but values, so you won't get `results[1,1], results[1,2], ...` but the values of `PE` and `w` instead. For that to work you should use `i` and `j` as indexes by doing `1:length(PE)`, and getting the terms of `PE` by `PE[i]`, and the same for `w`.

```
for(i in 1:length(PE)){
  for (j in 1:length(w)){
    results[i,j] <- (1+PE[i] - (1+(PE[i]^w[j]))^(1/w[j]))
  }
}
```

Comment: `result <- sapply(w, function(j) (1+PE - (1+(PE^j))^(1/j)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
w <- seq(1, 4, by = 0.1)
PE <- seq(1, 2, by = 0.1)

results <- sapply(w, function(j) (1+PE - (1+(PE^j))^(1/j)))

for(i in 1:length(PE)){
  for (j in 1:length(w)){
    results[i,j] <- (1+PE[i] - (1+(PE[i]^w[j]))^(1/w[j]))
  }
}

results 

write.table (results, file = "results.csv", sep = ",")
```

Comment: why are you are calculating the elements of `results` twice (once before the loop and then in the loop)?